# App playing up after being reinstalled

Tags: android, debugging, sharedpreferences

My login system uses SharedPreferences to store information about the user. The main two variables for the login system are:

- loggedin - boolean
- userID - int of the userID that's logged in (primary key on the DB)

When the user logs in, loggedin is set to 1 and the userID is set to the user ID fetched from the DB. When the logout button is pressed loggedin is set to 0 and userID set to null.

Situations:

- I log in, close the app and repoen it = fine, still logged in to the correct account
- I log in, then logout, close & reopen the app = fine, comes up with login screen
- I carry out invalidate caches and restart in android studio = fine, stays logged in on the correct account.

Now here's the one that's going wrong: If I login, then uninstall the app off my phone and press run on android studio the app launches and logs in to a really old account that no longer exists on the DB; and I can't work out why this is happening.

My only thought is there is a userID stored on the device that isn't being removed, but that could be completely wrong. Any ideas?

I've added some log tags throughout the code and before the app is uninstalled the userID is correct and when it's been reinstalled it's the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Shared Preferences` are always cleared along with uninstalling app.
But since **android-21** Backup task stores preferences by default to cloud. Later when you uninstall then install newer version .You are probably going to use restored preferences. To avoid that, just add this to your `manifest` ( or at least manifest for debug). -

```
<application ...
    android:allowBackup="false">
 ...
</application>
```

Read this:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

It's Important to mention here that process of backup is blackbox .. you don't know when it starts, and period between checks ... so better for developing to disable it.

Comment: That's sorted it, knew it was something like this but couldn't find what :) Thanks!